# Forms not displaying on click btn

Tags: jquery, forms

i have 3 forms in my code. onload i want only form 1 to be displayed, when submit1 if pressed then form 2 should be displayed and form 1 & 3 shud be hidden when submit2 is clicked then form 3 should be displayed

with modification based on suggestion the code i added the ids and style...onload it loads form 1 and hides 2&3 **but now** on submit1 clicking it reloads the form 1 instead of loading form 2 and hiding form1

```
<script type="text/javascript">    


$(function submitform() {
    $( "#dialog-message" ).dialog({
      modal: true,
      buttons: {
        Ok: function() {
          $( this ).dialog( "close" );
          window.location = "http://mysiteloc.com";
        }
      }
    });
  }); 


 $("#submit1").click(function(e) {
    $("#form2").show();
    $("#form1").hide();  
     $("#form3").hide();   
    e.preventDefault();
});

$("#submit2").click(function(e) {
    $("#form3").show();
    $("#form1").hide();
    $("#form2").hide();
    e.preventDefault();
});

  </script>
<body>
<form id="form1" method="post" >     

            <div>
                <input type="text" id="inputemail" name="email" placeholder="Email" height="34px" required>
            </div>  
            <div >
                <button id="submit1" type="submit" name="submit1" ><strong>Start</strong></button>
            </div>      
 </form> 

<form id="form2" method="post" style="display:none">         

            <div>
                <input type="text" id="inputpwd" name="pwd" placeholder="Password" height="34px" required>
            </div>
            <div >
                    <button id="submit2" type="submit" name="submit2" ><strong>Next</strong></button>
            </div> 

 </form>  

<form id="form3" method="post" style="display:none"> 
        <div required>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="0" name="book_type[]"> Romance</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="1" name="book_type[]"> Action</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="2" name="book_type[]"> suspense</input><br>
                    <input type="checkbox" value="3" name="book_type[]"> thriller</input><br>
                </div>
                <div >
                    <button id="submit3" type="submit" name="submit3" onclick="submitform();"><strong>Next</strong></button>
                </div> 
</form>
</body>
```

Comment: This is jquery, not PHP

Answer (score 0):

You need to add id's to your submit buttons as that is what you're using to capture the click event:

```
<button type="submit" id="submit1" name="submit1" ><strong>Start</strong></button>
```

You could also change your jQuery selector to just use the name attribute:

```
$('button[name="submit1"]').click(function(e) {
```

To hide the second and third form initially use a CSS rule:

```
#form2, #form3 {display: none;}
```

Comment: i added the ids and style...onload it loads form 1 and hides 2&3 but on submit1 clicking it reloads the form 1 instead of loading form 2 and hiding form1

Answer (score 0):

Try setting your form like this:

```
<form id="form2" method="post" style="display:none">
```

I don't think tagging it in the form will work the way you have it.